# php some digits from string

Tags: php, regex

I have the next strings:

```
generation_1_2
generation_2_8
generation_3_12
```

How can I put digits from this strings in variables?
For example:

```
$digit1[0] is 1.
$digit1[1] is 2.
$digit1[1] is 3.
$digit1[0] is 2.
$digit1[1] is 8.
$digit1[2] is 12.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Somehow your "next strings" don't match with your example. Please specify.

Comment: it should be " $digit1[2] is 3 " thats it

Comment: and " $digit2[1] is 8 "?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function ret_int($str){
    return array_slice(explode('_', $str), 1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to extract the trailing numbers you can do:

```
if(preg_match_all('/(\d+)$/m',$input,$m)){
   // $m[1] will have all the matches.
}
```

[working link](http://www.ideone.com/nrWId)

**EDIT:**

Answer to your edited question to extract both the digits:

```
$digit = array();
if(preg_match_all('/(\d+)\D*(\d+)$/m',$input,$m)) {
        $digit = array_merge($m[1],$m[2]);
}
```

[Working link](http://www.ideone.com/fKpF2)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to extract the digits from the strings, you can [explode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php) them like fabrik wrote (`$arr = array_slice(explode('_', $str), 1);`).

Then using [intval](http://php.net/manual/de/function.intval.php), convert each of them to integers like this: `$int_a = intval($str_a, 10)` where `$str_a` is one string from the array `$arr`.